# How to Get FreeBSD Grep to recognize '-' option?

Tags: grep

I am using FreeBSD grep, version 2.5.1, and want to be able to have grep read the pattern from stdin. Other versions of grep I have used allow for the specification of `-` to enable this feature. However, the version I have does not recognize this option. Is there an alternative option I simply missed in the "man page" or does FreeBSD grep, 2.5.1, not support such capability?

Comment: You're talking about `grep -f -`?

Comment: Do you mean *pattern* from stdin, as in `printf pattern | grep -f - files_to_search`, or haystack from stdin as in: `tail file_to_search | grep pattern -` ?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect by "other versions of `grep`" you mean [GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) and are thinking of its `-f` option, which allows a `-` argument to make it behave as you say.

BSD `grep` does support `-f`, but it requires an actual file as an argument. It indeed won't take `-` as an argument.

All is not lost. You can still pass the pattern to `grep` via command substitution:

```
$ grep `my-pattern-producing-command` some-files*
```

Or if the pattern is in a file:

```
$ grep `head -1 my-pattern-file.txt` some-files*
```

Or, just install GNU `grep`:

```
$ cd /usr/ports/textproc/gnugrep
$ sudo make install clean
```

By the way, SysV `grep` doesn't support `-f` at all, so that's another reason to be careful about relying on it. That said, Solaris is now shipping GNU `grep` by default. You actually have to go out of your way to use SysV `grep` on Solaris.